# Gauge transformation of gauge fields in the adjoint representation

Tags: yang-mills

In some Yang-Mills theory with gauge group $G$, the gauge fields $A_{\mu}^{a}$ transform as
$$A_{\mu}^{a}
        \to A_{\mu}^{a} \pm \partial_{\mu}\theta^{a} \pm f^{abc}A_{\mu}^{b}\theta^{c}$$
$$A_{\mu}^{a}
        \to A_{\mu}^{a} \pm \left(\partial_{\mu}\theta^{a}-A_{\mu}^{b}f^{bac}\theta^{c}\right)$$
$$A_{\mu}^{a}
        \to A_{\mu}^{a} \pm \left(\partial_{\mu}\theta^{a}-iA_{\mu}^{b}(T^{b}_{\text{adj}})^{ac}\theta^{c}\right),$$

where $T^{a}_{\text{adj}}$ is the adjoint representation of the gauge group $G$ and the gauge parameters $\theta^{a}$ are seen to transform in the adjoint representation of the gauge group $G$.

---

Why does this mean that the gauge fields $A_{\mu}^{a}$ transform in the adjoint representation?

Should the transformation of the gauge fields $A_{\mu}^{a}$ in the adjoint representation not be given by

$$A_{\mu}^{a} \to A_{\mu}^{a} \pm i\theta^{b}(T^{b}_{\text{adj}})^{ac}A_{\mu}^{c}?$$

Comment: Except for the $\partial_\mu\theta$ term in the last expression, and perhaps up to a sign, you wrote the exact same thing four times. Are you asking how to show that the four expressions are the same thing? Or you already know that?

Comment: I would like to prove that the third term is equal to the fourth term.

Comment: You can't because they are not equal. The $\partial_\mu\theta$ term is missing in the fourth expression. It should be there.

Comment: I know! But it is said that both $\theta$ and $A_{\mu}^{a}$ transform in the adjoint representation. But it appears that their precise mathematical transformation is different.

Comment: Ah, that's the problem: $\theta$ does **not** transform in the adjoint representation. In fact, it does not transform at all: it is this function what parametrises the transformation itself. This is similar to when you perform a translation $x\to x+a$ - the vector $a$ does **not** transform.

Comment: Well, the third line clearly shows that $\theta$ transforms in the adjoint representation. The index on $\theta$ is paired with an index of the representation matrix!